# How to convert a particular field from String to ObjectId in an entire collection of mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

"products" collection in my mongodb is mentioned as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a67755082edf74a06fc92c9"),
    "productName" : "Printer", 
    "productId" : "5a677550d3a2246da136f294"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6a67755082edf74a06fc92cd"),
    "productName" : "Scanner", 
    "productId" : "5a688550d3a2246da136f297"
}
```

Now, I'm trying to update the productId field's value from String to ObjectId in an entire product collection. So that the output should look like as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a67755082edf74a06fc92c9"),
    "productName" : "Printer", 
    "productId" : ObjectId("5a677550d3a2246da136f294")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6a67755082edf74a06fc92cd"),
    "productName" : "Scanner", 
    "productId" : ObjectId("5a688550d3a2246da136f297")
}
```

I had tried using the following query

```
db.products.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { db.products.update("productId", {$set:{"productId":  ObjectId(myDoc.productId)}})} );
```

But, I'm facing the below error:

```
E QUERY    [thread1] Error: invalid object id: length :
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Answer (score 1):

> E QUERY    [thread1] Error: invalid object id: length :

This happens when your `productId` field is `null`, missing or otherwise is not a valid ObjectId-like string (24 hex digits).